# concat two array[row] element in map

Tags: string, apache-spark, concatenation, rdd, case-class

I have Array[Row]
I am using case class to map it to get RDD

```
case class MyClass(string,long)


  sparkSession.sparkContext.
    parallelize(row.map(r1 => 
   MyClass(r1.getString(0).concat(r1.getString(1)),
   r1.getLong(2))))
```

There 3 fields in array row.
I want to concat 1 and 2 fields...r1.getString(0).concat(r1.getString(1)) with a separator "-"

> input array row = ["string1","string2",someLOngnum]
>
> Expected Output RDD with case class = ["string1-string2",someLongnum]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Input:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
//data: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([AAA,a,100], [BBB,b,200], [CCC,c,300])


val result = rdd.map(r => myClass(r.getString(0) +'-'+ r.getString(1),r.getLong(2)))
//result: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[myClass] = MapPartitionsRDD[15]
```

Output:

```
result.collect.foreach(println) 

//myClass(AAA-a,100)
//myClass(BBB-b,200)
//myClass(CCC-c,300)
```